# Python urllib timeout error even with headers for certain websites

Tags: python, timeout, urllib

I'm writing a simple Python 3 script to retrieve HTML data. Here's my test script:

```
import urllib.request

url="http://techxplore.com/news/2015-05-audi-r8-e-tron-aims-high.html"

req = urllib.request.Request(
    url, 
    data=None, 
    headers={
        'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11',
        'Referer': 'http://www.google.com'
    }
)

f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

This works fine for most websites but returns the following error for certain ones:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out>
```

The URL shown in the script is one of the sites that returns this error. Based on research from other posts and sites, it seems like manually setting the user-agent and/or the referer should solve the problem, but this script still times out. I'm not sure why this is occurring only for certain websites, and I don't know what else to try. I wold appreciate any suggestions the community could offer.

Comment: Have you tried python-requests http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/?

Comment: Never heard of it, but it looks useful. I'll make a note of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the script again today without changing anything, and it worked perfectly. Looks like it was just something strange going on with the remote web server.